# SciPy optimization for FEA truss structure

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to optimize the weight of a truss structure by changing the areas. I have this (shortened/verified code for FEA truss) where x is a array of element areas:

```
stresses = np.zeros(10)

def FEA(x):
   #code to calculate stresses, weight

   stresses = element_stresses
   return weight
```

I then have a constraint function like this:

```
def eval_constraints(x):
    global stresses
    constraints = [stresses[0]/25-1, stresses[0]/-25-1,
            stresses[1]/25-1, stresses[1]/-25-1,
            stresses[2]/25-1, stresses[2]/-25-1,
            stresses[3]/25-1, stresses[3]/-25-1,
            stresses[4]/25-1, stresses[4]/-25-1,
            stresses[5]/25-1, stresses[5]/-25-1,
            stresses[6]/25-1, stresses[6]/-25-1,
            stresses[7]/25-1, stresses[7]/-25-1,
            stresses[8]/75-1, stresses[8]/-75-1,
            stresses[9]/25-1, stresses[9]/-25-1]

     return constraints
```

The optimize command is as such:

```
x0 = np.full(10,5.)
bnds = [(0.0, None)] * 10
cons = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': eval_constraints}]
result = minimize(FEA, x0, bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
```

What happens now is that the derivatives with respect to each x variable get computed. But then the optimzation suggets 0.0 for all the areas. This violates the constraints:

```
[5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
[5.00000001 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
[5. 5.00000001 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
[5. 5. 5.00000001 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
[5. 5. 5. 5.00000001 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
[5. 5. 5. 5. 5.00000001 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
[5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.00000001 5. 5. 5. 5.]
[5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.00000001 5. 5. 5.]
[5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.00000001 5. 5.]
[5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.00000001 5.]
[5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.00000001]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

I even try setting bnds = [(0.1, None)] * 10, but it doesn't move that far from the x0 value.

```
'Positive directional derivative for linesearch' error
[4.99996444, 4.99996444, 4.99996444, 4.99996444, 4.99996444,
   4.99996444, 4.99998758, 4.99997551, 4.99996445, 5.00053543]
```

The optimized value is [7.90, 0.10, 8.10, 3.90, 0.10, 0.10, 5.80, 5.51, 3.68, 0.14]. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos,sin
from scipy.optimize import minimize, fmin_slsqp

#nodes: x, y
nodes = np.array([[720, 360],
            [720, 0],
            [360,360],
            [360,0],
            [0,360],
            [0,0]])

#materials: E, rho, sigmaT, sigmaC
materials = np.array([[10000, 0.1, 25, 25],
                [10000, 0.1, 75, 75]])

#boundary conditions: nodeID, xDOF, yDOF
boundaries = np.array([[5, 0, 0],
                [6, 0, 0]])

#concentrated loads: nodeID, xLoad, yLoad
cloads = np.array([[2, 0, -100],
            [4, 0, -100]])

#generic element stiffness matrix
bar_truss_element_k = np.array([[1, 0, -1, 0],
                        [0, 0, 0, 0],
                        [-1, 0, 1, 0],
                        [0, 0, 0, 0]])

def T_matrix(theta):
    T = np.zeros((4,4))
    T[0,0] =  T[1,1] = T[2,2] = T[3,3] = cos(theta)
    T[0,1] = T[2,3] = sin(theta)
    T[1,0] = T[3,2] = -sin(theta)

    return T

 def element_L_and_theta(node1, node2):

    diff = node1-node2
    L = np.linalg.norm(diff)
    theta = np.arctan2(diff[1],diff[0])

    return L, theta

def FEA(x):

   #elements: node1, node2, A, matID
   elements = np.array([[3, 5, x[0], 1],
                    [1, 3, x[1], 1],
                    [4, 6, x[2], 1],
                    [2, 4, x[3], 1],
                    [3, 4, x[4], 1],
                    [1, 2, x[5], 1],
                    [4, 5, x[6], 1],
                    [3, 6, x[7], 1],
                    [2, 3, x[8], 2],
                    [1, 4, x[9], 1]])

    #Intialize matricies and vectors
    num_DOFs = nodes.shape[0] * 2
    stiffness_matrix = np.zeros((num_DOFs, num_DOFs))

    forces = np.zeros((num_DOFs,1))
    for nodeID, xLoad, yLoad in cloads:
        nodeID = int(nodeID)
        forces[2*(nodeID-1)] = xLoad if xLoad != 0 else 0
        forces[2*(nodeID-1)+1] = yLoad if yLoad != 0 else 0

    #Compute the stiffness matrix
    for element in elements:
        node1, node2, A, matID = element
    
       node1, node2, matID = int(node1)-1, int(node2)-1, 
                             int(matID)-1

       E = materials[matID][0]

       L, theta = element_L_and_theta(nodes[node1],nodes[node2])
       T = T_matrix(theta)

       element_k = (A*E/L) * np.transpose(T) @ 
            bar_truss_element_k @ T

       stiffness_matrix[np.ix_([2*node1, 2*node1+1, 2*node2, 
       2*node2+1], [2*node1, 2*node1+1, 2*node2, 2*node2+1])] += 
       element_k

   #Identify and eliminate zero DOFs
   zero_DOFs = [2*(condition[0]-1)+i for condition in boundaries 
   for i,DOF in enumerate(condition[1:]) if DOF==0]
      non_zero_mask = np.ones(num_DOFs, dtype=bool)
      non_zero_mask[zero_DOFs] = False

   reduced_stiffness_matrix = stiffness_matrix[non_zero_mask][:, 
   non_zero_mask]
   reduced_forces = forces[non_zero_mask]

   #Solve for the displacements
   reduced_displacements = 
   np.linalg.solve(reduced_stiffness_matrix, reduced_forces)
   displacements = np.zeros((num_DOFs,1))
   displacements[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(num_DOFs), zero_DOFs)] = 
   reduced_displacements

   #Solve for the forces
   forces = stiffness_matrix @ displacements

   #Solve for the element stresses
   element_stresses = np.zeros(elements.shape[0])
   weight = 0.0
   for i, element in enumerate(elements):
       node1, node2, A, matID = element
    
   node1, node2, matID = int(node1)-1, int(node2)-1, int(matID)-1

    E = materials[matID][0]

    L, theta = element_L_and_theta(nodes[node1],nodes[node2])

    element_stresses[i] = (E / L) * np.array([np.cos(theta), 
    np.sin(theta), -np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)]) @ 
    displacements[[2*node1, 2*node1+1, 2*node2, 2*node2+1]]
    weight += L*A*0.1 #rho=0.1

stresses = element_stresses
return weight

def eval_constraints(x):
    global stresses
    constraints = [1-stresses[0]/25, 1-stresses[0]/-25,
            1-stresses[1]/25, 1-stresses[1]/-25,
            1-stresses[2]/25, 1-stresses[2]/-25,
            1-stresses[3]/25, 1-stresses[3]/-25,
            1-stresses[4]/25, 1-stresses[4]/-25,
            1-stresses[5]/25, 1-stresses[5]/-25,
            1-stresses[6]/25, 1-stresses[6]/-25,
            1-stresses[7]/25, 1-stresses[7]/-25,
            1-stresses[8]/75, 1-stresses[8]/-75,
            1-stresses[9]/25, 1-stresses[9]/-25]

return constraints


x0 = np.full(10,5.)
FEA(x0)
#x_correct = np.array([7.90, 0.10, 8.10, 3.90, 0.10, 0.10, 5.80, 
5.51, 3.68, 0.14])
bnds = [(0.1, None)] * 10
cons = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': eval_constraints}]
result = minimize(FEA, x0, bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
print(result)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing method to another that supports constraints and bounds, and seeing if that helps? You could try either `trust-constr` or `COBYLA`. Docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Comment: Other than that, it's hard to give a suggestion without a working FEA function. Can you make this example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @NickODell I tried using different solvers no change. Here is the code I used above. Thanks

Comment: Can you fix the indentations and newlines in this code? As is, the code has a bunch of indentation errors.

Comment: Running this, I notice a bug: the code assumes that SLSQP will call the objective function, then the constraint function with the same x. SLSQP doesn't always do that. Sometimes it calls the constraint function a bunch of times with different x values. This means that sometimes the constraints will falsely tell SLSQP that a point satisfies the constraints when it doesn't.

Comment: This might work better for sharing calculations between constraint and cost function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60957024/scipy-optimize-minimize-constraints-depend-on-cost-function

Comment: @Nick Odell thanks for looking at this. I ended up solving the problem by getting rid of the global stresses variable and creating a new FEA_elementStress function to calculate the element stresses in the constraint equation. For my type of problems this is little impact on efficiency.